# I cant figure out how to make two choices then show what your choice was

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Okay this is the whole thing right now.
The section commented 'From here' is giving me trouble. The rest of it works how I want it too but I cannot for the life of me get this. I have googled this so many times Im being advertized java lessons and coding classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Text adventure</h1>
<p>By Caleb Scott Sanders</p>
    <p id="1"></p>
    <p id="2"></p>
    <p id="3"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innnerHTML = confirm("Sup");
        </script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "you wake up in a dark and dusty room, its cramped and only two potential exits. The door or the window.";
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "1: check door 2: check window";
        </script>
        <script>//From here
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
                choice = prompt();
                if(choice = a){
                    document.getById("3").innerHTML = "The door has a large iron lock with equaly large bars. This seams more like a cell gate than a door...";
                } else if(choice = b) {
                    document.getById("3").innerHTML = "The window is open but looks too small to crawl through. No way out from here.";
                };

        </script>
    <p id="3"></p>// to here is the problem
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what Ive done wrong because I cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a few things...

1. I don't know why you are using `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =`, but don't.
2. Use three equal signs for comparing, one equal sign is for setting value.
3. Surround a and b in quotes, they are not variables, they are strings.
4. It is `getElementById` not `getById`.

For future reference try using the console, it will lead you in the right direction.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Text adventure</h1>
<p>By Caleb Scott Sanders</p>
    <p id="1"></p>
    <p id="2"></p>
    <p id="3"></p>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("demo").innnerHTML = confirm("Sup");
        </script>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = "you wake up in a dark and dusty room, its cramped and only two potential exits. The door or the window.";
            document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "1: check door 2: check window";
        </script>
        <script>
                var choice = prompt();

                if(choice === "a"){

                    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "The door has a large iron lock with equaly large bars. This seams more like a cell gate than a door...";
                }else if(choice === "b"){

                    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "The window is open but looks too small to crawl through. No way out from here.";
                };

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```